# Algorithm optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Say you wanted to find which input causes function x to output value y, and you know the (finite) range of possible inputs.

The input and output are both numbers, and positively correlated.

What would be the best way to optimize that?

I'm currently just looping through all of the possible inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to make a guess with this little information. Are you looking for a specific output? If you've got a derivative for your function x, [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) is fast. If you don't have a derivative, the [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) is a reasonable second choice. If the function is monotonically increasing or decreasing with respect to the input variable, a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) might be just the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be a binary search over the possible inputs.

Flow:

```
find the median input x
get the output from function(x)
if the output is less than the desired y
    start over using the smaller half of the possible inputs
else
    start over using the larger half of the possible inputs
```

Answer (score 1):

A binary search algorithm, perhaps?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If the range is finite and small, a precomputed lookup table might be the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

if you have some sets of know "x" data that yield "y" you can divied between training and test sets and use neural networks.